# Чем распределенная ВС отличается от кластерной?

Tags: терминология

Для кого-то это, может, и элементарный вопрос, но я, побродив по Сети, особой разницы не увидел.
По-моему, это одно и то же. И там, и там объединены компьютеры...

Можете очень просто, на пальцах, показать, что такое РВС, КВС и в чем разница.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Кластерная ВС является частным случаем распределенной системы
2. Принципиальным отличием кластера от обычной распределенной ВС, это то что кластерная ВС может рассматриваться как одна система. Типичный пример кластеризованная БД, с точки зрения конечного юзера она представляет собой одну базу данных
3. Для кластера принципиально важным является наличие быстрой связи между отдельными узлами (иначе невозможно организовать синхронизацию между узлами и соответственно потеряется возможность рассмотрения набора узлов как единой системы)

Answer (score 0):

Одним из преимуществ кластеризации является превосходное соотношение цена/производительность. Кластер любой производительности можно создать, соединяя стандартные ВМ, при этом его стоимость будет ниже, чем у одиночной ВМ с эквивалентной вычислительной  мощностью.

Comment: Это вы обьяснили мне что такое кластер/кластерная ВС) Согласен) А что такое распределенная вычислительная система? Насколько я понял, это тоже самое, что и кластерная ВС. Но какая-то разница должна быть?

Comment: @Get, в самом деле?

Вы пишете:

      ... соединяя стандартные ВМ, при этом его стоимость будет ниже, чем у одиночной ВМ с эквивалентной вычислительной мощностью.

Зачем же тогда вообще использовать одиночные ВМ? Для пыли в глаза, чтобы показать всем, насколько я богат?

--

Правильный ответ -- это высказывание справедливо, начиная с некоторого уровня производительности.

Кстати, вообще-то неплохо бы указать, Вы говорите о HA или HPC кластерах?

--

Что  же касается вопроса ТС, то я бы сказал, что это почти синонимы - граница размыта, определяется уровнем связанности узлов и внешней памяти.

Comment: Кластерная - это ВС из кластеров, т.е. групп ВМ. На кластеры можно отдавать более емкие задания и не беспокоиться о распределении ресурсов между их более мелкими составляющими. Одиночные ВМ используют тогда, когда кластер получается дороже для решения задачи. И в том, и в другом случае получается распределенная ВС, но менее или более масштабная.

Comment: @Get, из Ваших определений следует, что кластерная ВС (кластер) это штука более масштабная, чем просто распределенная система.

Как думаете, что масштабнее -- SETI@home (однозначно распределенная, но вряд ли кластерная) или типичный двухузловой HA microsoft cluster в небольшом отделении какого-нибудь банка?

Comment: По-моему, мы сравниваем оранжевое и апельсин. Кластерная сеть однозначно распределенная, как минимум внутри кластера, но не всякая распределенная состоит из кластеров. При этом использование готового кластера в определенных случаях гораздо удобнее сети из одиночных машин. Как минимум за счет отсутствия необходимости дробления и распределения задач каждой машине.

Comment: @Get, а вот сеть из одиночных машин называть распределенной ВС не стоит.

Кластер (независимо от типа) это распределенная ВС, но очевидно, что далеко не всякая распределенная ВС является кластером. 

--

Думаю, можно остановиться на цитате из вики:

    Один из первых архитекторов кластерной технологии Грегори  Пфистер дал кластеру следующее определение: «Кластер — это разновидность параллельной или распределённой системы, которая:
    
    1. состоит из нескольких связанных между собой компьютеров;
    2. используется как единый, унифицированный компьютерный ресурс».

Comment: Мы вернулись к определению кластера. Помог ли ТС наш диалог?

Comment: Ну, это его надо спросить. 

Смею  надеяться, что помог. Добавил отрицательных определений.

Из положительных (после ответа @Barmaley ♦) я бы подчеркнул, что для кластера важно наличие единого логического центра управления (хотя физически он может быть распределенным).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно что есть что)